# Generate probability density after single sensor measurement

Tags: robotics

In MCL localization, the robot is able to generate a density map after receiving a single sensor scan. An example is given on page 10 of the following link.

http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/thrun.robust-mcl.pdf

I wonder how Figure 3 is generated given only a sensor scan and a wall map?

Answer (score 0):

> Fig. 3c probability distribution for different poses

It indicates probability of scan `o` being taken at different locations {x1, x2, ...xn}.

[image]

In `Fig.3c`, these probabilities are plotted such that higher the probability higher the darkness.

I guess these positions of particle are taken from `Fig. 6a` as example. You can see in `Fig. 3c` that particles in the corridor have high probability (more dark).